# Get-azureRmDisk does not show property DiskState

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I need to get property like "DiskState", I am using cmd-let Get-AzureRMdisk, and what I got:
1) from my laptop, using `connect-azurermaccount` then `get-azurermdisk`, doesnt give expected property 2) I tried from Automatio account, created a runbook and then paste my code there, the same, I got more values but didn't get "diskstate" value 3) I see that I can get it from Azure Cloud Shell console. I would like to get this value from a script running as a runbook. Moreover I tried to use command like --> `Get-AzureRmDisk | Where-Object ManagedBy -ne $null`, but didnt get any interesting results. Is there any matheto do get this mentioned property "diskstate" using powershell runbook from Automation account?

Comment: Do you just want to get the disk state in the runbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not, the PowerShell command `Get-AzureRMDisk` show you the `DiskState` as you want:

[image]

Additional, I recommend you use the Az module of the PowerShell while the AzureRM module is Migrated to it. See [Migrate Azure PowerShell from AzureRM to Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-2.6.0).

Update:

But in the Runbook `Get-AzureRMDisk` does not show the property, you need to use the `Get-AzDisk` to achieve the purpose after you import the Az module and it shows like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thx for this, but as I mentioned, I know that from Powershell Cloud shell from the portal I can get this info. I need it from runbook from automation account.

Comment: @CharlesXu I suppose You are right, but problem is that I cant update modules AzoreRM --> AZ, so I have to upload date from Cloud shell. i am using commands like: `Get-Azdisk | Export-Csv "$Env:temp/AutomationFile.csv"
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "<StorageAccountKey>"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $Context -Container "xxx" -File "$Env:temp/AutomationFile.csv" -Blob "SavedFile.csv"`, and I have error --> Export-Csv : Access to the path '/AutomationFile.csv' is denied.

Comment: I removed azurerm, installed az on my local laptop, connected to azure subscripction and run script from my laptop, and results are ok. AZ module resolved the problem.